# How to remember viewstate after redirecting?

Tags: viewstate, webforms

Main page has a gridview with options to filter / search etc...

when a user selects a row a NEW page comes up (response.redirect) and i can edit/insert/delete there...

I want the user to be able to go back to the page he came (easy) BUT i want the grid to have the filters as they where on the time of the first redirect.

anything ready in .net or i have to use lets say querystring back and forth to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `Response.Redirect`

Instead of using `Response.Redirect`, use `Server.Transfer` where ever you can. `Response.Redirect` sends response to the client which then sends a new request to the server. `Server.Transfer` however performs the redirect on the server. Only use `Response.Redirect` when you want authentication and authorization to be performed on redirects or you want URL on client browser to be changed because `Server.Transfer` will not do this as it is a server side transfer.

This way you'll be able to preserve the prvious page folrms collections..
look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/74472/ViewState-and-Server-Transfer-Best-practices

and also "Passing Server Control Values Between Pages" :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score -1):

[Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) will return the previous URL request. Use hidden controls to retain the value if you use MVC

Comment: mm, i am on web forms..so i suppose that i have to get the url from the urlreferrer and pass in querystring my 6 numbers for the dropdownlist values.....